# How could I delay the camera preview so that it shows what's happened x seconds before?

Tags: android, kotlin, camera, android-camera2

I have a simple android app with a camera preview.

**I would like to set the preview so that it shows what happened x seconds before.**

I'm trying to do a buffer but it looks like there are no way to control what's inside the preview.

I use `camera2` and a `textureView` for the preview.

Do you have any ideas, or library that could help me ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You need to cache ~30 preview buffers somehow.

One possible way is to use an ImageReader where you wait for 30 onImageAvailable callbacks to fire before you acquire the first Image.  But this requires you to draw the Image yourself to the preview TextureView once you start acquiring them, which is difficult to do correctly before Android Q's ImageReader with usage flags constructor.

You can also cache things in OpenGL; use a SurfaceTexture and a GLSurfaceView, and copy the SurfaceTexture frames to a list of 30 other textures in a circular buffer, then start rendering when the 30th one is drawn.  But requires quite a bit of scaffolding code to implement.